# Why do bank statements end on *SUCH* wildly inconsistent days of the month?

Tags: banking, financial-statements, bank-statements

When I look at when I get my bank statements, I have a hard time finding *any* bank that is consistent.
Bank of America is a particularly good example of how erratic these can be:

```
Statement until 2016-05-05, notification email sent on 2016-05-07
Statement until 2016-06-07, notification email sent on 2016-06-09
Statement until 2016-07-06, notification email sent on 2016-07-08
Statement until 2016-08-08, notification email sent on 2016-08-10
Statement until 2016-09-07, notification email sent on 2016-09-09
Statement until 2016-10-05, notification email sent on 2016-10-07
Statement until 2016-11-03, notification email sent on 2016-11-05
Statement until 2016-12-06, notification email sent on 2016-12-08
```

And the weirder thing is, this is *after* I called about a year ago to request that the statements end on the *3rd* banking day of the month (they let me choose between the 3rd-18th, or the last banking day).

For the life of me, I cannot comprehend why it's so hard for them to have any kind of consistency.

Why in the world do banks seem to be so random about when they end their statements?
Isn't it just a computer doing the work? Or is it some dude sitting there processing these by hand, getting tired, and putting it off until the next day? Or are they pulling accounting tricks of some sort?

Comment: is it a bank statement (for a checking /savings account) or is it a credit card statement?

Comment: @mhoran_psprep: a checking account statement

Comment: See also http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/6812/credit-card-statement-dates-follow-pattern

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at your dates, I think I see a pattern.  It appears that your statement closing date is always 17 business days before the last business day of the month.  For example, if you start at May 31 and start counting backwards, skipping Saturdays, Sundays, and May 30 (Memorial Day), you'll see that May 5 is 17 business days before May 31.  I cannot explain why Bank of America would do this.  If you ask them, let us know what they say.

If it bothers you, find another bank.

I do most of my banking (checking, savings, etc.) with a local credit union. Their statements end on the last day of the month, every month without fail. (Very nice, in my opinion.)

I have two credit cards with nationally known banks, and although those statements end in the middle of the month, they are consistently on the same date every month. (One of them is on the 13th; the other date I can't recall right now.)

You are right, a computer does the work, and your statement date should be able to fall on a weekend without trouble. Even when these were assembled by hand, the statement date could still be on a weekend, and they just wouldn't write it up until the following Monday.

You should be able to find another bank or credit union that does this.

Comment: Same here, except it's half a dozen credit cards, one of which (and a mortgage) is with BoA.  Go figure...

Comment: You seriously think this is a reason to change banks?? I couldn't care less which day they print the paper, and I find it hard to see why anyone would care. It sounds like changing the bank because the print their statements in Arial font instead of the much nicer Tahoma, or such?

Comment: Ben, how is a span from the 3rd to the 8th explainable by a "weekend"? I would understand if it was 5th to 7th, but 3rd to 8th??

Comment: I also don't understand why both of you are focusing on why it "bothers" me. Whether or how it is bothering me is irrelevant to the question. I'm trying to understand what's going on, simple as that. If you don't know then just don't answer...

Comment: @Mehrdad My answer to your question is in my fourth paragraph: essentially, there is no good reason, in my opinion.

Comment: @BenMiller: But what I'm asking for is not a justification -- I'm just asking what the de-facto reason *is* (even if it's a horrible reason). Has someone programmed it to be random? Is someone doing something manually even when everything on my account is electronic? etc.

Comment: @Mehrdad I think I found the pattern.  Your statement closing date is 17 business days before the last business day of the month.  Answer updated.

Comment: @BenMiller: Now *that* looks like the right explanation! Mind blown! Thanks a ton!! Now time to check my other banks to see if I can find something similar haha.

Comment: Update -- it seems you're right! They mostly seem to be on the Nth business day; BoA seems to be the exception in this regard of N days before the last business day. Thanks!!

Comment: Addendum: it still doesn't seem foolproof (e.g. Oct. 5 is actually 18 business days from the end, and in Chase -- which counts from the beginning -- I also seem to see a discrepancy in October), but at this rate it really does seem like they're consistent unless something unusual happens. Thanks!

Comment: @Mehrdad Don't forget about Columbus Day (October 10).

Comment: @BenMiller: Ooh, that explains it! [This page](http://www.theholidayschedule.com/banks/chase-bank-holidays.php) didn't list it! Any idea where I can find a better list? (Sorry for going on a tangent...)

Comment: @Mehrdad How about [this one](http://www.theholidayschedule.com/banks/bank-of-america-holidays.php)?  Even that one is not complete, however, because you have to count two holidays for Thanksgiving (Thursday and Friday) to make that one work out.

Comment: @BenMiller: Yeah, that list looks better. It doesn't seem like I need to count Friday though -- it's 19 - 1 (Veterans' Day) - 1 (Thanksgiving) = 17.

Comment: @Mehrdad You are right; I missed Veterans Day.

Comment: So I checked all of the banks & credit cards I could get my hands on, and I found everyone does pretty much their own thing; most have a pattern, although I did find one that I can't explain. A couple of other interesting ones: (1) Citi (credit card) seems to be consistently doing "Nth business day" according to that list of holidays, except it doesn't seem to think of Jan 1 and Jul 4 as holidays! (2) American Express (credit) happily falls on a weekend, but constantly flips between the Nth and Nth+1 calendar day... go figure.

Answer (score 3):

They need to spread the work for all customers over the whole month, and they don't work on weekends.
Combine the two, and the rule becomes clear - if months have minimum of N working days, 1/N of all customers gets set on each day. You seem to be on day 5:
If the month starts with a Monday, the fifth *working day* is the 5. (Friday); if there is a Sat or Sun in between, it will be the 6th, and if there is both a Sat and a Sun in there, it will be the 7th.

However, the statement itself is not very important at all. It is just the day where they print it on paper (or even only on a PDF). You can see your bank account activity every day 24/7 by checking online, and nothing keeps you from printing it on every 1st of the month if you want (or every day, or whenever you prefer).

Comment: But there are only 19 working days in February in the US, except in a leap year. There are 20 week days, but one of them is Presidents' Day, which is a federal bank holiday.

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense to me unfortunately. (a) *What work* is there to be done in the first place? Isn't the data already online like you said? I'm not even receiving these by mail; I'm only getting PDFs! (b) Even if there is work to be done, isn't it done by a computer? (c) If I'm on day 5, weekends explain the 6th and 7th, but how can it vary from the **3rd** to the **8th**? Why would it ever end *earlier*, and why would it be delayed by 3 days rather than 2? Nothing here actually makes sense! (As for your last point: whether/why I should/do care is irrelevant and not my question.)

Comment: What work: printing and mailing. If you think printing and mailing 50000 statements is no work, think again. There are whole supplier chaines living from this. You are right that it does not explain the rest. They must just not take it very serious, or they start their 'months' on the 15th.

Comment: @Aganju: I thought I just said there is nothing to be printed or mailed.

Comment: @Mehrdad Even when computers do the work, the capacity [server sizing] etc, makes it more prudent for Bank to spread out the statements over month. Not knowing how BOA works, I can say most Banks try to a) even out the load over month, i.e. dispatch statements on different days like card companies. b) Inherent data transfers between multiple IT systems that adds to delays.

Comment: @Dheer: That sounds plausible at least, but hardly convincing. The reason being that whether you process everyone's statement on *exactly* day X or whether you process it on day X *on average* plus some random noise of +/- day or two, the expected server load for every day of the month will be the same. I do realize there is a *little bit* of room for optimization given that everyone's account usage varies throughout the year, but given the large number of users, it's a little hard to swallow that this effect is so large (and they're so short on server $$$) that they're actually optimizing it.

Comment: @Mehrdad a few decades ago, much of it was printed or mailed, an computers were orders of magnitude less powerful so it certainly made sense to optimize for it. And once such a standard is estabilished and ingrained in many processes (both software and purely organizational), it's hard and expensive to change it, so it will stay around unless it causes real problems - and the described situation seems to be just a quirk; a new system would avoid it but it's not harmful enough to justify the effort of implementing and testing a significant change in how their processes work.

Comment: @Peteris: How likely do you think it is that this explanation is correct though? (I realize it's just speculation, but I'm wondering if you're 10% confident about it or 50% or 90%...)

Comment: @Mehrdad for this instance it is just speculation, but I have seen enough quirks in banking systems for which the reason truly was "because it had to be this way 25 years ago, and there's no reason to change now".

Comment: @Peteris: Seems like I was right about that explanation being wrong. See the accepted answer.

Comment: but in terms of development and maintenance cost, it is MUCH easier to write the system such that it will issue ALL statements by the end of the month, and in such case you can have the whole middle of the month to do system maintenance / repair / upgrade / etc. without disrupting the business cycle